# Two <%# Eval("Id") %> in same form, only one works

Tags: asp.net, binding

I have the following bindings. However, only the first binding works. The second is always null. How can I make both of them work well?

```
 <tr>
   <th>
        <a href="SettingsOperator.aspx?id=<%# Eval("Id") %>">Settings</a>
   </th>

 </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>
        <a href="ShareEmployees.aspx?id="<%# Eval("Id") %>">Import Employees</a>

     </th>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second binding is incorrect. Compare it to your first, the extra double quotes is what is causing the problem. Substitute the first set of double quotes for single quotes and it should work.

Id=`<%# Eval("Id") %>`

Sorry, doing this from a smart phone, and the single quotes aren't working for some reason. The single quotes should go before the first angle bracket and after the last angle bracket.